# Border-image not working for QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a class derived from QWidget.  When I try to use the style-sheet to set the border-image, it appears to ignore it.  I am using QT 4.4 and it looks like the QWidget should support border-image.  Is there something I would need to do in the paint event to get it to display, or something else I am missing?

Also, is it possible to define a series of images for the border, using border-top-left-image and the rest?

Comment: Qt 4.4? Isn't Qt on 4.7 right now, getting ready for 4.8?

Comment: Yup.  I am working on a legacy product and am stuck at this version for now.

Comment: Isn't `border-image` a CSS3 property? I wouldn't think that an older version of Qt would support it.

Comment: It should be supported, according to this: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image

Comment: There are a lot of stylesheet things not implemented in Qt 4.4. Especially for windows. For example Gradient for text. Works perfectly in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Try subclassing QFrame instead of QWidget.  I've never seen a border* style sheet work on a plain QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a paint event for your QWidget-derived-widget to make sure it loads the stylesheet.

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    QStyleOption option;
    option.init(this);
    QPainter painter(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &option, &painter, this);
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```